# loop through multiple input fields on a form and push to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a form with a lot of inputs and values. I want to push all the data to a firebase database. I could assign variables to each field value as:

```
let name = $("#field1").val();
let surname = $("#field2").val();
```

etc etc, but this feels very inefficient.

I want to create a object and loop through all input fields and map their name and value, something like this:

```
const collection = {};

$('form input').each(function () {
    collection[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

Then I want to push all the data to firebase. But how do I push the entire object to firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as simple as:

```
firebase.database().ref().push(collection);
```

Of if you want it under a specific location/path in the database:

```
firebase.database().ref("specific/place").push(collection);
```

Btw: I highly recommend reading the [Firebase documentation on reading/writing lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).